# How WINAPI handle IAudioClient->SetEventHandle() works?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, audio-recording, wasapi

I'm writing an application that reading audio endpoint on windows, via WASAPI. For now I have similar code for capture thread (treat this code as minimal example):

```
DWORD CWASAPICapture::DoCaptureThread()
{
    BYTE *pData;
    UINT32 framesAvailable = 1;
    DWORD  flags, state;

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Unable to initialize COM in render thread: %x\n", hr);
        return hr;
    }

    while (framesAvailable != 0) {
        // get the available data in the shared buffer.
        state = WaitForSingleObject(_AudioSamplesReadyEvent, INFINITE);
        hr = _CaptureClient->GetBuffer(&pData, &framesAvailable, &flags, NULL, NULL);
        if ((state != 0) || (hr != S_OK)) {
            // my breakpoint
            assert(false);
        }

        UINT32 framesToCopy = min(framesAvailable, static_cast<UINT32>((_CaptureBufferSize - _CurrentCaptureIndex) / _FrameSize));

        if (flags & AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT)
        {
            ZeroMemory(&_CaptureBuffer[_CurrentCaptureIndex], framesToCopy*_FrameSize);
        } else {
            CopyMemory(&_CaptureBuffer[_CurrentCaptureIndex], pData, framesToCopy*_FrameSize);
        }

        _CurrentCaptureIndex += framesToCopy*_FrameSize;

        // release data
        hr = _CaptureClient->ReleaseBuffer(framesAvailable);
        assert(hr == S_OK);
    }

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

In Init section I requested buffer for 1s duration, blockAlign equal to 8, so my captureBufferSize = 3528000 bytes. _AudioSamplesReadyEvent set as _AudioClient->SetEventHandle(_AudioSamplesReadyEvent). Packet size = 441. Other code based on official windows SDK [CaptureSharedEventDriven](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/multimedia/audio/CaptureSharedEventDriven) example, [this method](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/blob/master/multimedia/audio/CaptureSharedEventDriven/WASAPICapture.cpp#L306) I changed.

### Problem:

Program always fails on my breakpoint (by design) and i'm watching into variables, expected values are hr = AUDCLNT_S_BUFFER_EMPTY (0x08890001) and _CurrentCaptureIndex = 3528000, and I even got this values like in 1 from 10 cases... Usually hr = AUDCLNT_S_BUFFER_EMPTY (0x08890001) and _CurrentCaptureIndex equals to random values, most often is 0, 3528 (8 packets) and 10584 (24 packets).

First of all, when I just started to use WaitForSingleObject with _AudioClient->SetEventHandle, I supposed it signals when buffer is filled for requested time in _AudioClient->Initialize() ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd370878(v=vs.85).aspx) description pretty fluent), but that wrong, next my suggestion was that it waits until a single packet with data got filled, but as my example shows, I don't have available frames in buffer. I tried ti use GetNextPacketSize nex to WaitSingleObject, but still the same result.

### My questions is:

1. Why my example works that way?
2. What exactly IAudioClient->SetEventHandle() signaling about to WaitForSingleObject()?
3. How to read buffer of size I requested properly?

---

**UPD1:** `Sleep()` placed before while, instead of `WaitForSingleObject()` works fine, I get all frames for time my thread slept.

**UPD2:** [minimal example](https://gist.github.com/Liastre/ff201f37bc62f6dc0b7f5541923565ab)

Comment: implementation of IAudioClient->SetEventHandle()  simply save handle of your event and call `SetEvent` when data is ready.

Comment: @RbMm First "data is ready" what **part** of data is ready, all requested buffer, one package, some random number of frames? After all, if data is ready for processing, why I get AUDCLNT_S_BUFFER_EMPTY, that means there no any pending data... it's very confusing me.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you created a manual reset event.  You *must* then call ResetEvent() to clear it before you call WaitForSingleObject().  If you don't then the second and subsequent calls to WFSO complete immediately and GetBuffer() can't work correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant placing `ResetEvent(_AudioSamplesReadyEvent)` before `WaitForSingleObject` doesn't solve the problem, also I get code from official SDK example (link in my post), it's not manual reset event and there no ResetEvent() for it at all. Though, in original one was used WaitForMultipleObjects.

Comment: Don't have us guess. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable, look, I linked SDK example I used, and linked method I changed in there, I have no idea why you decided to guessing. Anyway minimal example was added.

Comment: I didn't ask for a *"minimal example"*. I asked for a [mcve]. Links to off-site resources aren't considered part of the question. See [ask] for guidance.

Comment: @IInspectable I included minimal source code (link to my gist) that reproduce the problem, it's Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable! Just create new Visual Studio project and compile the source. See [How to Create a project from existing code files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfzh36t7.aspx) for guidance.

Comment: *"Links to off-site resources aren't considered part of the question."* A question needs to be self-contained.